# jupyter cannot find my conda env

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook, conda

I have a conda env in this directory in my mac
`/anaconda/envs/dl`
then I start my conda env by `activate source dl`

and when I start the jupyter it does not show the conda env dl, and only shows that its using python3 but not the conda env.
`Notebook python3`

[image]

And if I click terminal it shows this.

[image]

Comment: Please do not put error messages in images, see here for the reason: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2449192

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install nb_conda , it should work.

Answer (score 3):

You need to install *nb_conda*, however, at the moment [nb-conda cannot be directly installed with python3.6](https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/1423).

A way around that is to install it from conda-forge:

`conda install -c conda-forge nb_conda`

And also do not forget to install jupyter notebook on the new environment.

Comment: conda install -c anaconda nb_conda
https://anaconda.org/anaconda/nb_conda

Answer (score 0):

To use jupyter notebook inside a virtual environment, ipykernal is required to be installed in your venv.

```
Inside your virtual environment:

pip install ipykernel

Then run the kernel "self-install" script:

python -m ipykernel install --user --name=my-virtualenv-name
```

Now, your new kernel has been installed.